# Does there exist an Ordinal Turing Machine program which can detect the occurrence of accidentally writable reals on the tape of a simulated program?

Tags: logic, set-theory, computability, ordinals, turing-machines

Assuming that $p$ denotes a particular [OTM program](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0502264), let $x$ denote a real which is *accidentally writable* on the initial segment of length $\beta$ of the tape of $p$ at a particular time $\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is an arbitrary countable ordinal.

Question: does there exist an OTM program $P$ which (given an input real with a suitable encoding of the combination of $\alpha, \beta, x$) can simulate the computational process of $p$ and provide the correct answers to any question of the following type:

> Is it true that $x$ is accidentally writable on the initial segment of length $\beta$ of the tape of $p$ at time $\alpha$?

I am interested in two situations: (i) $\beta = \omega$ (the smallest limit ordinal); (ii) $\beta$ is an arbitrarily large countable ordinal.

That is, if $x$ does, in fact, occur on the initial segment of length $\beta$ of the tape of $p$ at time $\alpha$, the $P$ program should output "Yes". Otherwise, the program should always output "No."

Comment: I am confusing about your definition. Are reals a binary sequence of length $\omega$? Then what is the meaning of *$x$ occur on the initial segment of length $\beta$*? Does it mean $x$ occurs somewhere on the tape, between the 0th cell and the $\beta$th cell?

Comment: @HanulJeon: A real is a binary sequence that _can be_ represented as a sequence indexed by natural numbers, which is equivalent to a sequence of length $\omega$. But, for example, if a real occurs on the initial segment of length $\beta = \omega + \omega$, it means that a real is written on cells indexed by $0, 1, \ldots, \omega, \omega + 1, \ldots$ up to an $(\omega + \omega)$-th cell. You can encode this situation by a single real of length $\omega$.

Comment: So may I replace your 'real $x$' with 'binary sequence $x$ of length $\beta$?'

Comment: It seems that you are asking whether the questions of following type can be answered by a program/machine:"Is it true that a binary sequence $x$ of length $\beta$ appears on the initial segment of length $\beta$ of the tape of $P$ at time $\alpha$ (during some computation)?" Given the binary sequence itself and $\beta$, $\alpha$, index of $P$  as inputs ..... it should be answerable by simulating $P$. Its correct that if $\beta$ is countable then a binary sequence of length $\beta$ can represented by two (and hence one) real numbers.

Comment: One real number of would describe well-order (on $\mathbb{N}$) of order-type $\beta$ and other would describe what is present on those positions.

Comment: @HanulJeon: yes. Specifically, it is a "binary sequence $x$ of length $\beta$ which appears on the initial segment of length $\beta$ of the tape of $p$ at time $\alpha$." All of this information is supposed to be encoded by a single binary sequence of length $\omega$ and given to $P$ as input.

Comment: I corrected the nasty typo in the formulation of the problem. Sorry for the confusion! The lower-case $p$ denotes a simulated program, and the upper-case $P$ denotes a program which performs a simulation of the computational process of $p$.